# How to rewrite my code with streams - could it be even done?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I produced this nested loops solution with label for breaking the iteration over two nested collections. Is there (and I hope there is) some more elegant solution that this? (e.g. streams, avoiding the label etc.?)

This algorithm should only check the first unitLine from the first unit and if there are some lookupResults the algorithm setType(TYPE1) else setType(TYPE2). So I know in advance that I need to check only first object from both collection and then I can quit.

Thank you!

```
List<String> lookupResults;
    outerloop:
    for (Units unit : units) {
        for (UniteLine unitLine: unitLine.getUnitLines()) {
            lookupResults = findLookup(LOOKUP_CODE, unitLine.getCode());
            if (lookupResults != null && !lookupResults.isEmpty()) {
                someObject.setType(TYPE1);
                break outerloop;
            } else {
                someObject.setType(TYPE2);
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this question is offtopic for [so]. May be the site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the existing logic may be changed like this using `Stream.flatMap` and `Stream.findFirst`:

```java
lookupResults = units.stream() // Stream<Unit>
     .flatMap(unit -> unit.getUnitLines().stream()) // Stream<UnitLine>
     .map(unitLine -> findLookup(
         LOOKUP_CODE, unitLine.getCode()
     )) // stream lookupResults
     .findFirst() // Optional lookupResults
     .orElse(null); // unwrapped lookupResults

someObject.setType(lookupResults != null && lookupResults.isEmpty() ? TYPE1 : TYPE2);
```